# What applications or utilities would update Tridion's XML schemas?

Tags: configuration, cme, upgrade, media-manager

I'm dealing with a situation where I have installed the Media Manager connector for Tridion 2011 in two environments. In one environment, the connector worked fine. In the other, the Tridion GUI throws an error message on the ECLEEditor.config file where it doesn't recognize a particular namespace.

Through poking and prodding, I discovered that in the Web/WebUI/Core/Schemas directory, my `Extensions.xsd` file and my `ConfigurationMerge.xsd` file were different.

Specifically, Extensions.xsd  was missing this:

```
<xs:element name="xslstylesheetextensions" type="merge:xslStylesheetExtensionType" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Defines the XSLT stylesheet extensions</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
 </xs:element>
```

I updated my test environment to have matching XML schemas as my dev environment (and restarted everything), but the error persists. This leads be to believe that there are more differences between my environments that I haven't noticed, yet - and I'm at a loss as to how these files ended up being different to start with.

Would an upgrade or a hotfix to Tridion involve editing these XML Schemas? If this is the case, which ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue indeed was caused by cumulative hotfix 81958 not being installed before running the Media Manager Connector installer.

Answer (score 5):

Media Manager connector shipped with a "cumulative hotfix" that is needed on Tridion 2011SP1. I do not remember the exact number of this hotfix, but I think it was included with the install files for the Media Manager Connector. If not you can get it from SDL support.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I got the Connector from SDL to begin with. I followed their instructions to the letter when I installed the connector in both of my environments. Is there any reason the exact same cumulative hotfix would run in one environment, but not the other?

Comment: A computer can always come up with a reason to do the unexpected. :)
Maybe a file was locked or something like that. I would run the hotfix again and check the output of the install carefully.